# Fastlane is freezing when trying to upload to Testflight

Tags: react-native, fastlane

I'm trying to upload my iOS file to Testflight with Fastlane. It all works fine for the android part. However, when it finished building for iOS and tries to upload it it gets stuck on my M1 Macbook. See screenshots below:

Get stuck here:

[image: Terminal]

After a while it gives this error:

[image: After a while it gives this error]

The weird thing that happens then is that internet doesn't work anymore on my macbook. It's basically stuck somehow and I have to restart it to get it to work again.

I've tried multiple times, 5 or so, and 1 of them succeed. The other tries got stuck.